# Does the Query Optimizer have the right to create Temporary (Materialized) Views if it enhances performance?

Tags: optimization, temporary-tables, materialized-view

Does the Query Optimizer have the right to create Temporary (Materialized) Views which can enhance performance? Sorry if this question seem very trivial.

Or in other words, does the query optimizer consider plans which involve creating a temporary table, storing the object on disk and then using it for query execution.

Comment: Are you talking about in general? Or a specific product?

Comment: You need to specify which DBMS you have in mind